# How do I fix maximum recursion depth exceed without import sys

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to do a recursion problem and the code works 3 out of 5 times. The 2 failed tests have the “maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison error”. I have tried the import sys method but my laptop can only go up to 2000 before stack overflow. The 2 failed tests failed at n=8, m<=8 and n>0 , m=0

Here is what I have put down so far.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000)

def howManyGroups(n,m):
    m = min(m, n)
    if n == 0 or m == 1:
        return 1
    return howManyGroups(n, m - 1) + howManyGroups(n - m, m)
```

Comment: Please post your real code. What you show has a syntax error. Also show some examples of how you call your function. Do they all result in recursion error?

Comment: Did you mean to write: `m = min(m, n)` ? Now you may have overwritten `m`

Comment: Most often it's a bad idea to configure the recursion limit.
In most of the cases reaching this limit points a bad recursive design.

Comment: Hello, I have just edited the code it should work now

Comment: Note the **double** recursion on line `return howManyGroups(n, m - 1) + howManyGroups(n - m, m)`. Each call to `howManyGroups` triggers two more calls to `howManyGroups`. This is an exponential chain reaction, the kind of scary stuff that makes nuclear bombs blow up. FIrst you start with one call. This call triggers two calls. These two calls trigger a total of 4 calls. These 4 calls trigger a total of 8 calls. These 8 calls trigger a total of 16 calls. Etc. You need to find a way to avoid this double recursion.

Answer (score 2):

1. fix your code, it's outright broken for m<1 as the code will recurse infinitely (probably other cases as well)
2. stop writing deeply recursive code in Python, the language is not designed for that and gets very unhappy
3. switch to Python 3.11, [it has stopped using the C stack for the Python callstack](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89419), now you can consume all the machine's memory when you implement an infinite recursion

Comment: Hi, what do you mean m<1 in my code? did you mean m - 1?

Comment: No I mean that if you pass a `m` which is strictly smaller than 1 (m < 1), like 0, the code will loop forever, because you keep decreasing `m`, and you decrease `n` by `m`, with a negative `m` you're thus increasing `n`. As a result `m` will decrease forever and `n` will increase forever, and your termination conditions will *never* trigger.

Comment: The maintainers reject the idea of stackless Python, so Python 3.11 still has the recursion limit.
https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89419#issuecomment-1093930341

Comment: @RezaKGhazi while Python 3.11 is not stackless, because it consumes no C stack during pure python recursion you can set the recursion limit *much* higher. On my Linux system on 3.10 a recursion limit of 2^14 will trigger a recursion error but 2^15 will trigger a segfault. Doing the same stunt on 3.11, my machine started swapping and slowed to a crawl before I found any sort of limit, I was at 2^26 (but I only have 16GB RAM, the recursing cpython process exceeded 14GB).